# some margin at the top google chrome and opera

Tags: html, css

There is margin >10px in the top of the page in Opera and Chrome. When I opening console I see that all of meta tags, scripts and other files who must been located in header is in body. Also after opening  tag are some 2-line space. There is static page an in other pages work correctly. In Firefox all work correctly.
What is that? And how I can kick it?

Comment: try reproducing the problem and show us only the code needed, create a fiddle with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with de default margin of the browsers.

css:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Or to set all elements defaults to `0`

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: I have: body{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px;}

Comment: Also I have *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

Comment: This problem is only in admin page. I think this troubles create plugin easy tabs, but why there is work correctly in Firefox?

Comment: Im sorry but we need some html to

Comment: http://unitedshop.com.ua/ you can open console and see html. On each page isset part of HTML who started from '<!DOCTYPE>' tag and ended in '<div id="wrapper">'

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t31/1540346_681146538609855_1332225238_o.jpg screen from opera (also that all look like this in Google Chrome)

Comment: my last advise is, check if everything is closed well and check if your html and css is valid.. to see the errors..

Comment: I am sure that every tag is closed, so that the page is generated from separate parts, and $this->view(footer) locked all tags opened in $this->view(header)
But despite the fact that could not solve the problem, I really thank you for patience towards the noob.

Comment: No problem, everybody starts somewhere learning programming! ;)

Answer (score 0):

> "This problem is only in admin page."

Maybe there's admin bar CSS that's throwing you off?

Is this only a problem when you are logged in back-end? Looking at your site, there's no funny margin-top on the body, over here that is.